# Deleting a range from a table with merged cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is this: Delete all rows from a table starting from where the cursor is in the table to the end of the table.

The problem is that this table contains vertically merged cells, so when I try to do something like this:

```
For i = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count To Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex Step -1
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

It complains that individual rows cannot be accessed because the table contains vertically merged cells.

I've also tried selecting the range first, and then deleting the selection. But I couldn't get the range definition right; it always complained that there was an improperly defined parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't merged table cells just a pain in the rear with VBA?  Word seems to get confused with the column and row count.  The follow seems to be pretty robust with any combination of horizontally or vertically merged cells.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=(Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count - Selection.Cells(1).RowIndex), Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Rows.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: @Totty What table layout have you got?  I've tried it with an absolute bunch of different combinations of vertical and horizontal merges and can't get it to fail once.

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong it works.. I missread the question... What I've been looking for was to delete all empty rows in a verti-horiz merged cells...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851957/how-to-delete-all-blank-or-with-spaces-rows-in-a-table-that-has-one-or-more-cell

Comment: No problems, I'll have a look

Comment: How to alter this code to work with deletion of Columns? It works but delete merged cells it is merged horizontally.

Comment: I'll have a look for you when I get a chance @Raj.  Probably best to post as a new question linking to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer as I attempted CuberChase solution but it did not work with my table:

[image: Table Screenshot]

Notice I have vertically merged rows in columns 1, 2 and 5. When I implemented `Selection.MoveDown` with the intent of selecting all rows within the parent "A3" row, it did not recognize the internal rows in columns 3 and 4. It instead selected the parent "A4", "A5" and "A6" rows (same format as A3) without selecting any internal rows.

Here is what I had to do in the end to successfully delete the parent and child rows in my table. I first had to collect the indices for the first cell in each row to delete into an array. I reversed my array in order to work from the bottom up so as not to change the indices at runtime.

Then I looped through my reversed array, selecting the range of cells belonging to each parent row and deleting the rows associated with my selection.

```
  table = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For Each idx In ReverseArray
      cells_to_delete = ActiveDocument.Range(Start=table.Range.Cells(idx).Range.Start, End=table.Range.Cells(idx+*count_of_cells*).Range.End)
      cells_to_delete.Select
      Selection.Range.Rows.Delete
  Next idx
```

No idea if anyone else has come across a similar problem, but I figured I'd put the answer up here in case someone does. :)

Comment: how to achieve it in C#?