# How to delete blank rows or rows with spaces in a table that has one or more cells vertically merged?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a vba script or help on what I'm writing in order not to exit the iteration when the table contains **vertically and horizontally merged cells**.

Example of the table:

```
---------
|   |   | <-- I don't want these rows deleted, they can be skipped
|---|   |
|   |   | <-- I don't want these rows deleted, they can be skipped
|---|---|
|   |   | <-- this must be checked for emptiness in order to decide to delete or not
|---|---|
|   |   | <-- this must be checked for emptiness in order to decide to delete or not
|---|---|
```

My script in VBA so far:

```
Public Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim c As String
    c = ""
    Dim oTable As Table, oRow As Integer
    ' Specify which table you want to work on.
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

        For oRow = oTable.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            'On Error GoTo NextIteration
            MsgBox oTable.Rows(oRow).Range.Text
            'If Len(oTable.Rows(oRow).Range.Text) = oTable.Rows(oRow).Cells.Count * 2 + 2 Then
            If Len(Replace(oTable.Rows(oRow).Range.Text, Chr(13) & Chr(7), vbNullString)) = 0 Then
                oTable.Rows(oRow).Delete
            End If
        Next oRow
    Next oTable
    MsgBox c
End Sub
```

How to reproduce the error:
Create a 5x5 table. Select cell(0,0) and cell(1, 0) and merge them. Select cell(0, 1) and cell(0, 2) and merge. Run the script and get the 5991 error..

The problem is that I get a run-time error 5991: Can't access to individual lines in this collection because there are vertically merged cells.

I really don't know what to do because if this error happens no row will be looked after. Usually my tables have a header that has vertically merged cells and the body rows are not, so I cannot do anything...

for Word.

Comment: So to clarify do you want to delete rows only if they do not have a merged cell in them (be it vertical or horizontal) or if they have no merged cells but also no text?

Comment: Not exactly.. I want to skip the merged rows, but not to skip the whole table if there is any merged rows/cols in it...

Comment: Sorry but it's still unclear.  What exactly do you want to delete?  Is it any row in a table that is unmerged and without text?

Comment: yes, exactly. I don't care about the header, that usually contains merged cells. The body cells are usually not merged...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with to delete all rows in a table which do not contain any merged cells and do not contain any text.

The problem with tables containing merged cells is not so much deleting the rows but identifying which cells are actually merged and then removing whats left.

The way I approached this was to loop through all the cells in table and for each row workout how many columns are counted (horizontally merged cells and cells vertically merged from above are ignored) and thanks to this page (http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/GetRowColSpan.htm) 
if any of the cells in the row are the top of a vertically merged cell we can tell.

Finally we also check if there is any text in the row.

This is the code I came up with, hopefully with the comments it should be straightforward.  Unfortunately due to the way Word deals with this stuff the cells have to Selected rather than just using ranges - this isn't ideal because it significantly slows things down.  It has worked in all my tests.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim oTable As Table, oCol As Integer, oRows As Integer
    Dim iMergeCount() As Integer, dCellData() As Double
    Dim MyCell As Cell
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer, iRowCounter As Integer

    'Watching this happen will slow things down considerably
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Specify which table you want to work on.
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        'We need to store the number of columns to determine if there are any merges
        oCol = oTable.Columns.Count

        ReDim dCellData(1 To oTable.Rows.Count, 1 To 3)
        'The first column will count the number of columns in the row if this doesn't match the table columns then we have merged cells
        'The second column will count the vertical spans which tells us if a vertically merged cell begins in this row
        'The third column will count the characters of all the text entries in the row.  If it equals zero it's empty.

        iCurrentRow = 0: iRowCounter = 0
        For Each MyCell In oTable.Range.Cells
            'The Information property only works if you select the cell. Bummer.
            MyCell.Select

            'Increment the counter if necessary and set the current row
            If MyCell.RowIndex <> iCurrentRow Then
                iRowCounter = iRowCounter + 1
                iCurrentRow = MyCell.RowIndex
            End If

            'Check column index count
            If MyCell.ColumnIndex > VBA.Val(dCellData(iRowCounter, 1)) Then dCellData(iRowCounter, 1) = MyCell.ColumnIndex

            'Check the start of vertically merged cells here
            dCellData(iRowCounter, 2) = dCellData(iRowCounter, 2) + (Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber) - Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)) + 1

            'Add up the length of any text in the cell
            dCellData(iRowCounter, 3) = dCellData(iRowCounter, 3) + VBA.Len(Selection.Text) - 2 '(subtract one for the table and one for cursor(?))

            'Just put this in so you can see in the immediate window how Word handles all these variables
            Debug.Print "Row: " & MyCell.RowIndex & ", Column: " & MyCell.ColumnIndex & ", Rowspan = " & _
                (Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber) - _
                Selection.Information(wdStartOfRangeRowNumber)) + 1
        Next MyCell

        'Now we have all the information we need about the table and can start deleting some rows
        For oRows = oTable.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            'Check if there is no text, no merges at all and no start of a vertical merge
            If dCellData(oRows, 3) = 0 And dCellData(oRows, 1) = oCol And dCellData(oRows, 2) = oCol Then
                'Delete the row (we know it's totally unmerged so we can select the first column without issue
                oTable.Cell(oRows, 1).Select
                Selection.Rows.Delete
            End If
        Next oRows
    Next oTable

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wooow, it worked perfectly!! but what is the difference between selected and ranges? "Unfortunately due to the way Word deals with this stuff the cells have to Selected rather than just using ranges"

Comment: Well in my test table it worked perfectly but in the target table it misses some of the rows.. No problem because about 90% is done by your script, the rest I manually break the table with a custom made macro and then I run the script again. Thanks, it just deleted a lot of empty rows already. We needed this because we are re-designing the catalog in InDesign and the spaces between the table were slowing the things down because they should manually be deleted one by one in InDesign. Now it's copy-paste almost everything, I still wonder what other automation could be done for this..Thanks again

Comment: Ok, so using `Select` is like using your mouse to click within the document.  Pretty much anything you can do with the mouse you can do with `Select`.  Ie doing `ActiveDocument.Paragraph(1).Select` and then `Selection.Font.Bold = True` selects the first paragraph and changes it to bold.  You can achieve the same thing without selecting by `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Font.Bold = True` which is quicker since Word updates the screen with `Select`.

Comment: As for the code not working if you drop a sample doc in dropbox, I'd be interested to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: I had a look at the document and I assume you're talking about the very thin cells between the rows of text? It skips these because they are in fact one long merged row.  You'd have to do a separate check to see if there was one cell in the row and I'd then check if that cell spanned the entire table width.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in your conditions `Range.MergeCells` property, which will return `TRUE` in case cells in the range are merged.

Comment: CORRECTION: The problem is not knowing it or not, but how to manage make it work as expected..