# Deleting columns from a table with merged cells

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-word

I'm trying to delete columns from a table which has horizontally merged cells

[image: table before delete columns]

```
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCell, Count:=3
Selection.Columns.Delete
```

Eventhough columns are getting deleted, merged cells are removed in the process leaving a broken table.

[image: table after delete columns]

Almost similar approach to delete rows works fine as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13818541/167726)

**Workaround**

I'm doing something like this as work around

```
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCell, Count:=3
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=WdUnits.wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Cells.Delete
```

Then setting width of Cell at index 1,2 to rest of the table rows. This way you can avoid merged cell getting deleted.

Comment: important question- which column (how many) you want to delete?

Comment: Delete 3 columns from the selected cell in the first picture.

Comment: Your workaround is great. I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 1):

Word tables are not always intuitive.  If a cell spans a column that is to be deleted, then the ENTIRE spanned cell will always be deleted, as you have shown.

When I'm NOT using VBA, I always unmerge cells before deleting rows or columns; otherwise Word's behavior is hard to predict.

Using VBA I would suggest the following:

```
'splits the header row of the current table into 7 cells
Selection.tables(1).cell(1,2).split numrows:=1, numcolumns:=7

'your code to delete columns
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCell, Count:=3
Selection.Columns.Delete

'merge the header row back into one span
ActiveDocument.Range( _
    start:= Selection.tables(1).cell(1,2).range.start, _
    end :=  Selection.tables(1).cell(1,5).range.end _
    ).cells.Merge
```

or for a more general approach, to delete n columns:

```
width = Selection.tables(1).columns.count - 1
Selection.tables(1).cell(1,2).split numrows:=1, _
     numcolumns:= width - 1
Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=WdUnits.wdCell, Count:= n
Selection.Columns.Delete
ActiveDocument.Range( _
    start:= Selection.tables(1).cell(1,2).range.start, _
    end :=  Selection.tables(1).cell(1,width-n-1).range.end _
    ).cells.Merge
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
Sub DeleteCols()
    Dim Col2Delete As Range
    Set Col2Delete = Selection.EntireColumn
    Col2Delete.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: EntireColumn is not available in Word tables. I believe that is an Excel only function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we must look at the table not as rows/columns, but as indexed cells. (fig.1)

[image]

Now, we should select a range that starts from second cell and end to the last cell.

[image]

Finally, delete selection columns

```
        Set Rng = Tbl.Range.Cells(2).Range
        Rng.End = Tbl.Range.Cells(Tbl.Range.Cells.Count).Range.End
        Rng.Select
        Selection.Columns.Delete
```